# Query for looping values in column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to make a query that moves values of only one column one row up ↑ at a time:

```
    +------------+----------------+
    | anotherCOL | values_to_loop |
    +------------+----------------+
    |          1 |              1 |
    |          2 |              2 |
    |          3 |              3 |
    |          4 |              4 |
    |          5 |              5 |
    |          6 |              6 |
    |          7 |              7 |
    |          8 |              8 |
    |          9 |              9 |
    |         10 |             10 |
    +------------+----------------+
```

So, the next time i run the query, it should look like this

```
    +------------+----------------+
    | anotherCOL | values_to_loop |
    +------------+----------------+
    |          1 |              2 |
    |          2 |              3 |
    |          3 |              4 |
    |          4 |              5 |
    |          5 |              6 |
    |          6 |              7 |
    |          7 |              8 |
    |          8 |              9 |
    |          9 |             10 |
    |         10 |              1 |
    +------------+----------------+
```

I need to loop the values of only one MYSQL COLUMN, as in move the values one ROW UP ↑ each time I run the query.

Notice: Tables provided are just illustrative, the data is different.

Comment: I bet your professor is looking for a self join over anotherCol = anotherCol + 1

Comment: Can we assume the first column is sequential starting at 1 without gaps? Will you know how many rows there are before the query starts?

Comment: SQL rows don't have any order. Therefore there no concept of "up" until you're more specific about how this is supposed to work. The answer you accepted relies on `anotherCOL` and you've later said we should ignore that column completely. Not making much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it within a single UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE tbl a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT values_to_loop
    FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) c
    ORDER BY anotherCOL
    LIMIT 1
) b ON 1 = 1
SET a.values_to_loop = 
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT values_to_loop
         FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) c
         WHERE c.anotherCOL > a.anotherCOL
         ORDER BY c.anotherCOL
         LIMIT 1),
        b.values_to_loop
    )
```

It works as follows:

1. Updates all records from tbl
2. Joins with a temporary table to retrieve the top value of values_to_loop (the one that will go to the bottom)
3. Set the new value for values_to_loop to the corresponding value from the next row (`c.anotherCOL > a.anotherCOL ... LIMIT 1`)

Notes:

- This works even if there are gaps in anotherCOL (eg: 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 15)
- It is required to use `(SELECT * FROM tbl)` instead of `tbl` because you're not allowed to use the table that you're updating in the update query

---

### Faster query when there are no gaps in anotherCOL

If there are no gaps for values in anotherCOL you can use the query below that should work quite fast if you have an index on anotherCOL:

```
UPDATE tbl a
LEFT JOIN tbl b on b.anotherCOL = a.anotherCOL + 1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT values_to_loop
    FROM tbl
    WHERE anotherCOL = (select min(anotherCOL) from tbl)
) c ON 1 = 1
SET a.values_to_loop = ifnull(
    b.values_to_loop,
    c.values_to_loop
)
```

Comment: Man, this is taking days in a table with 2 million records, got anything faster?

Comment: Are there any gaps between anotherCOL? (if there are only consecutive values we could use a different approach)

Comment: yes there are gaps, i reduced the time considerably changing select * with the actual column names, but still takes a lot of time, this needs to be executed in less than 20 seconds, its taking 30 minutes.

Comment: values_to_loop contains only consecutive values starting from 1?

Comment: no, the tables provided in the question are merely illustrative

Comment: I see no other option for this rather than adding an additional column where to store the ID of the next row and then joining by that column. This will require some complexity upon insertion/deletion but you will be able to join the table with itself a lot more faster when updating.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve created a sample table and added both a select to get the looped values and update to loop the values in the table. Also, using a @start_value variable to know the "1" which might be other. Try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table 
  (other_col INT, loop_col int);

INSERT INTO temp_table (other_col, loop_col) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO temp_table (other_col, loop_col) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO temp_table (other_col, loop_col) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO temp_table (other_col, loop_col) VALUES (4,4);
INSERT INTO temp_table (other_col, loop_col) VALUES (5,5);


DECLARE start_value INT;
SELECT  start_value = MIN(loop_col) FROM temp_table;

SELECT  T1.other_col, ISNULL(T2.loop_col, start_value)
FROM    temp_table T1
        LEFT JOIN temp_table T2
            ON T1.loop_col = T2.loop_col - 1;


UPDATE T1 SET
    T1.loop_col = ISNULL(T2.loop_col, @start_value)
FROM    temp_table T1
        LEFT JOIN temp_table T2
            ON T1.loop_col = T2.loop_col - 1;

SELECT *
FROM    temp_table;
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Step by step:

1 - created a temp_table with values 1 to 5

2 - declared a start_value which will keep the lowest value for the column you to need to loop through

3 - select all rows from temp_table self left join with same temp_table. join condition is on loop_col - 1 so it can shift the rows up

4 - the same self left join, but this time update the values in place too.

please note that in case i get a null value, it should be the start_value there, because it cannot match

Comment: Ok, edited - please check again - i also added the explanation of what the query is doing. let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these are what you had in mind:

```
update T
set values_to_loop = mod(values_to_loop, 10) + 1

update T
set values_to_loop =
    coalesce(
        (
            select min(t2.values_to_loop) from T t2
            where t2.values_to_loop > T.values_to_loop
        ),
        (
            select min(values_to_loop) from T
        )
    )
```